# Why does collectd keep complaining that 'read function of plugin thermal failed'?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to enable the thermal plugin.  When I start the daemon I see these mesages:

```
Starting Statistics collection and monitoring daemon...
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "syslog" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "thermal" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "battery" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "cpu" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "df" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "disk" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "entropy" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "interface" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "irq" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "load" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "memory" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "processes" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "rrdtool" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "swap" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: plugin_load: plugin "users" successfully loaded.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: Systemd detected, trying to signal readiness.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost systemd[1]: Started Statistics collection and monitoring daemon.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
Sep 17 14:19:56 myhost collectd[10589]: read-function of plugin `thermal' failed. Will suspend it for 20.000 seconds.
Sep 17 14:20:16 myhost collectd[10589]: read-function of plugin `thermal' failed. Will suspend it for 40.000 seconds.
Sep 17 14:20:56 myhost collectd[10589]: read-function of plugin `thermal' failed. Will suspend it for 80.000 seconds.
Sep 17 14:22:16 myhost collectd[10589]: read-function of plugin `thermal' failed. Will suspend it for 160.000 seconds.
Sep 17 14:24:56 myhost collectd[10589]: read-function of plugin `thermal' failed. Will suspend it for 320.000 seconds.
```

How can I determine why it's giving me 'read-function of plugin `thermal' failed.'?

Comment: How is the plugin configured in /etc/collectd/collectd.conf?

Comment: According to this issue reported in collectd [Github](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/1972) not defining devices in the configuration works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Peregrino69's suggestion worked.  I removed the device from the collectd.conf file.  It now looks like this:

```xml
<Plugin thermal>
        ForceUseProcfs false
        IgnoreSelected false
</Plugin>
```

The 'read-function failed' message is now gone.

Comment: Sorry - go ahead and post that answer @peregrino69 and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you - I really didn't think about - note taken :)